# Rails: How can I check if the access_token is expired?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, access-token

I'm writing an api for an android app with rails. Since I'm new to both rails and android, I cannot figure the access_token stuff out.

I have a Token model, each time the user logs in, a new access_token will be added to the tokens table. My question is if I set the expiration date == 3 days after the token is created, what's the proper way to validate this when the user sends a request with an access_token? How can I delete those expired tokens?

Here is my Token Model:

```
# Table name: tokens
#
#  id           :integer          not null, primary key
#  access_token :string(255)
#  user_id      :integer
#  created_at   :datetime         not null
#  updated_at   :datetime         not null

class Token < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible   :access_token, :user_id
  before_validation :generate_access_token
  belongs_to        :user

  validates :access_token, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :user_id,      presence: true, uniqueness: true

private

  def generate_access_token
    begin
      self.access_token = SecureRandom.hex
    end while self.class.exists?(access_token: access_token)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `expires_at` column to the Token model to handle that. You will also need a method of retrieving a new token which could either update the existing token's key and expiration or you can generate a new Token record for the user and return that instead. The latter is more of the approach that Facebook takes for it's access tokens.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I don't know whether I understand it right. If I use the later approach, the flow would be: when the user sends a request, check if the access_token exists, if yes, check if the current time > expires_at, if yes, delete the old token, ask the user to login again, then generate a new token. For those expired tokens that haven't been used in a request, just leave them in the table. Is that right?

Comment: Basically, yes. If you're using access tokens as part of an API, your API should respond with an error if the token is expired. That way the person writing code for your API can catch that and act accordingly. Keeping the old tokens around is up to you so you can tell them when it expired if you want. It's not completely necessary to do that but could be helpful.

Comment: Got it. I'm wondering that since it's just an API for our own android app, is it a common approach not to set the expires_at column, which means tokens only expire when users explicitly log out?

Comment: If you're authenticating users with a session from Devise or something, I'd just use that without API tokens actually. Since you control the android app, you don't necessarily need to have tokens. They're more useful when anybody can interact with your API.